# Entering certain words (or alphabets) into <textarea> by clicking buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make `button`s that type certain accented alphabets on a `textarea` (such as ö, ü) in order to utilize typing alphabets that do not exist on the English keyboard.

I want the button formatted either like this;

`<button id='oe' onclick="enter..()">ö</button>`

or like this;

`<input type="button" value="ö" onclick="enter('ö')" class="enterbutton">`

How can I make this possible? Any modifications are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `append` to the value of the `textarea` on `click` by passing the character as follows:

```js
function enter(character){
     document.getElementById('txt').value+=character;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txt"></textarea>
<button id='oe' onclick="enter('ö')">ö</button>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thanks

Comment: I found a problem though, I cannot type the alphabets with buttons anymore after I have typed some other alphabets myself.  
For example, I can type 'ööö' by only using the button, but after I typed something else or clicked elsewhere, the button's function is no longer valid. In other words, I cannot type 'abcöö' by only using the keyboard and clicking the button in order. Any suggestions?